# Reality of dynamical matrix without inversion

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, phonons

Assume throughout this question that we are working with non-relativistic phonons in the harmonic approximation.

The Hamiltonian for phonons in the harmonic approximation is usually taken to be the dynamical matrix, $D(\boldsymbol{k})$, which is the Fourier transform of the force constants and defined as (following notation from [here](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.40.1) (1))

$$
D_{\alpha \beta}(\kappa\kappa'|\boldsymbol{k})= \frac{1}{\sqrt{m_{\kappa}m_{\kappa'}}}\sum_{l'}\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial u_{\alpha l \kappa}\partial u_{\beta l' \kappa'}} \big|_0\exp[i\boldsymbol{k}\cdot (\boldsymbol{x}(l)-\boldsymbol{x}(l'))]
$$

Where $\kappa, \kappa'$ label the atoms in the unit cell, $l,l'$ label unit cells of the lattice, $\alpha, \beta$ label cartesian directions and $\boldsymbol{x}(l)$ labels the position of the center of cell $l$. $V$ is the potential, $u$ the displacement and $m$ the masses of the atoms. This can be thought of as a $3N \times 3N$ matrix in 3D, where $N$ is the number of atoms in the unit cell. It is independent of $l$ due to the translational symmetry. It is fairly straightforward to show that this matrix is Hermitian, and this is done in every textbook and also in (1).

It is also easy to see that $D_{\alpha \beta}(\kappa \kappa'|\boldsymbol{k}) = D^*_{\alpha \beta}(\kappa\kappa'|\boldsymbol{-k})$, corresponding to (spinless) time-reversal symmetry, from which it follows that if the system has inversion symmetry then $D$ can always be chosen to be real.

---

However, what happens if there is no inversion symmetry? Ref. (1) shows explicitly that $D(\mathbf{k})$ can always be chosen to be real at the Brillouin zone center and boundary (as there $\mathbf{k}\equiv -\mathbf{k}$). However, there is a fairly recent paper [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.09148)(2) which argues that the dynamical matrix can *always* be chosen real. This is based on associating the cell at $l'$ with the cell at $-l'$ (note that these are intra unit cell, not inter unit cell, so this does not assume inversion symmetry). This does not, however, appear to be peer-reviewed, and I have not been able to find this claim anywhere else. It also stands in stark contrast to ref (1). I have, however, so far been unable to find an error in their proof. Note that they work in a classical limit, but I fail to see how quantization would break the argument.

So is there always a (unitary?) transformation that makes $D(\boldsymbol{k})$ real? Are these issues discussed in detail anywhere?

(1) https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.40.1

(2) https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.09148

Comment: The link (2) has a comment: The second equality in eq. 11 does not hold for the general case. Thus, the conclusion does not follow from the premises and the claim of the paper is not proven. It appears the result was retracted.

Comment: Thank you for spotting that! That makes a lot of sense